# Deploying a web app that uses GraphViz

Tags: python, graphviz

I have created a Django web app that uses GraphViz to render .dot files and .png images of said .dot files, and I would like to deploy that app for a school assignment.

I have already deployed previous apps on pythonanywhere but never an app that uses another software like now.

How can I go through with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 2.7 and no virtualenv, then GraphViz is installed already and you should just be able to use it -- see [the batteries included list](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/).  If you're using a later version of Python, or a virtualenv, you'll need to install it -- see [this page explaining how to install modules for yourself](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules).

Comment: I already installed the modules I need, but is it enough to deploy my app since they are dependent on the software ?

Comment: I just deployed it and indeed it doesn't work properly since GraphViz is not installed

Comment: What error are you getting?  GraphViz is definitely installed.

Comment: I don't get any errors it's just that he images of graphes are not genrated like it should. Is it because i'm working with [graphviz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) instead of Pygraphviz?

Comment: Is this the same problem as at https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/10695/?  If so, let's continue the discussion there.